# Alter or Recreate and drop in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, view, alter

I'm new to this site and I would really appreciate if you help me out with this.

My question is: if you want to change a view which is not working properly for the user would you have to drop and recreate the view or just alter it in order for the view to effect the user?

I know my wording is a little off but if you guys can help me with this question it would be great

Comment: For a view, I'd go with alter, just because it preserves permissions.

Comment: Yes but would it affect the other user if i use alter?

Comment: The view is the same for everyone, if you change it, it changes for everyone, immediately.

Comment: **Read the docs!** [`ALTER VIEW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173846.aspx)

Comment: andrew i know but i think it matters if you drop and recreate it or use the alter statment

Comment: Go with ALTER! If there are rights bound to the VIEW (look at GRANT) you'll lose them. Sometimes it even could not be allowed to drop the view if it is used within any context.